# Sharing files with others using iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, icloud

From what I know, iCloud is like a personal storage and you uses your own Apple ID for it. Is it possible for users to store for example an image and be shared with other users?

Which means something like DropBox. You upload files into your DropBox account and there will be a url that allows other people to download the file.

Does iCloud has this kind of function?

Comment: As djacobson pointed out below, I don't believe iCloud was ever meant to replace or compete with services like Dropbox--it's just a better way of keeping apps and files in sync across different devices.

Comment: Dropbox is perfect for what you want.  You can even use it to share a folder with another Dropbox user, and then both of you have access to any files you put in there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so, no. iCloud is meant to be a cloud-based backing store *for apps*, not a file-syncing service like Dropbox. It's a subtle difference, but consider that all interactions with your iCloud data happen through apps (Address Book, iCal, iPhoto, iTunes...), rather than with the individual files themselves.

So any sharing functionality for a given type of data will likely be delivered through the associated app(s). Whether it will make use of iCloud directly is uncertain, but although still in early days that doesn't seem to be the current pattern.

Comment: I wonder what will happen to iwork.com which hasn't seen any upgrades etc. for quite some time now. Ideally this would somehow get integrated into iCloud.

Comment: Presumably, yes. iCloud *already* has integration with the iOS version of the iWork suite; it would be extremely odd if they didn't have similar functionality for the desktop versions in iCloud as well.